# infinite scroll for datatables in coldfusion

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, coldfusion

I am very new to jquery and ColdFusion. I have a query which fetches almost 1000 data at once, because of which the performance of the site is very slow.
I am trying to implement the jQuery infinite scrolls on my page without using the pagination just the scroll and search option.

The foloowing is the code i am using:

```
$('#tblApprovedRequests').dataTable( {
     "bScrollInfinite": true,
     "bScrollCollapse": true,
     "sScrollY": "200px"
} );
```

What I am getting is just a paginated table with scrolls. But I need the data to load dynamically with the scroll so that the performance improves.

Can anyone help me to include infinite scroll in the coldfusion?

Comment: You probably have to cache the request. Use cachedWithin in your query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are two different technologies and there is more than one solution - all of which are probably beyond a stack overflow explanation. Let me see if I can outline it for you. Other than @AnitKumar 's suggestion (which might do the trick but may run afoul of other requirements), you will need to:

1. Figure out how to pull in the data in chunks. This usually involves finding a sort for your data (id, date etc) and then pulling out sections. For example you might pull from id 1 to 100, then 101 to 200 and so on. Or your DB might have a "rownumber" type function you can add to the query to give you a way to extract *just* the rows you want to display.
2. Create a function that returns the data as json and can be called from jQuery.
3. As your users scroll down you pre-populate the rows with data prior to the user getting to those rows. This requires some level of art and trial and error.

To summarize: Your initial view of the data loads up just the visible rows (and a bit more perhaps), and your scroll event triggers your JS to call your CFC to bring in more rows which are pre-pended to the bottom of the table and become visible as the scroll moves up. Does that make sense?

Note: this answer is theoretical and not typical for Stack Overflow. You should really experiement some more and come back with more specific questions related to debugging. It's important that you try some things before you post here. Just friendly advice. :)